# Java GC Stop and copy

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This question is a follow up to my previous Java GC question: [Java Garbage Collector clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729058/java-garbage-collector-clarification)

This question is also referring to the same article.

I'm a little confused on why the [stop and copy](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page426.html) method for defragmenting object heap allocation is so commonly used. Yes it defragments the heap however it seems like there is tons of overhead because basically you cut the total amount of heap size in half. Also you need to copy ALL the live objects when one half has run out of space.

Other than defragmentation is there any other fundamental reason why 'stop and copy' is better than say 'mark and sweep'?

Comment: You do realize that article is from 1996 and the world has moved on a lot since then, right? Take a look at the Sun Hotspot docs, in particular "tuning garbage collection," to see where things are today (I don't have a link convenient, but Google does).

Comment: Defragmentation doesn't necessarily cut the total amount of heap size in half. Some implementations may do that. Also it doesn't necessarily copy *all* the live objects.

Comment: Ok so I just googled 'tuning garbage collection' however I don't really understand the mechanism? Could somebody give a quick explanation?

Comment: There is no quick explanation. Garbage collection is complex :-)

Comment: @Thomas:  Also, since garbage collection is complex, it's very common to start with a simple technique (like reference-counting, in many cases), continue with a more complicated but more useful technique (like, say, stop-and-copy), and slowly evolve from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, fragmentation *is* fundamental, and the ability of some GC to defeat it is a considerable asset.

The stop-and-copy algorithm *used to be* popular in GC implementations because:

1. it is simple to implement;
2. it automatically defragments memory;
3. its running time is proportional to the amount of *live* objects, which makes it asymptotically very efficient.

More modern GC, including those used in Java, use much more complex strategies because they want to make *short pauses* (rather than making total GC time low, they prefer never to stop the application for a long time, because pauses are bad for interactivity), to interact more cleanly with caches and virtual memory, and to benefit from systems with multiple CPU.

The [Jones and Lins book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471941484) is a must-read for whoever wants to understand garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

A great tutorial on the garbage collector is [Tuning Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) (unfortunately the new oracle website has messed its formatting up quiet a lot).

Your question is handled in chapter V. This basically explains which types of strategies you can use in the Java garbage collector and which are default. Most desktop applications will be interested in a stop that is as small as possible, because this is what the user might notice.

Note that your question is not about defragmentation. Both will eventually compress the memory space.